# Kaminari pagination with conditions on rails

Tags: pagination, ruby-on-rails-3.2, kaminari

i am trying to add conditions to a Kaminari pagination on my rails project and i am finding it almost impossible. here is my code

```
  UserController
#feed=Feed.order('created_at desc').page(params[:page], :conditions=>["source=? or        source=?","beep","sub_beep"])
```

the above didn't work soo i tried the following

```
  @feed1 = Feed.find(:all,:conditions=>["source=? or source=?","beep","sub_beep"])
  @feed= Kaminari.paginate_array(@feed1).page(params[:page]).per(2)
```

the above displays contents but it doesnt display 2 contents per page and the displayed elements arent ordered.

i need a way to add conditions to kaminari pagination and order the result

please i need help!!! :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kaminari is designed to work with ActiveRecord 3+ style query interface only.

Please avoid using `:conditions` "Hasheritis" syntax which will be deprecated sooner or later, but chain with `where` method instead.

Usage of the `where` method is well documented here on the Rails Guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions

Your controller code should be like this:

```
feeds = Feed.where(:source => ['beep', 'sub_beep']).order('created_at desc').page(params[:page])
```